# Is "if (getline(fin, str)) {}" conforming to the C++11 standard?

Tags: c++, c++11, type-conversion, iostream, explicit-conversion

I checked the C++11 standard and found the following facts:

1. `std::getline(fin, str)` returns a `basic_ios` object, whose class has a member function `explicit operator bool() const;`
2. The class `basic_ios` doesn't have a member function `operator void*() const;` as pre-C++11.

So, I think `if (getline(fin, str)) {}` is not standard conforming. It should be written as

`if (bool(getline(fin, str)){}`. (However, VC++ 2012 gives a warning on this usage. i.e. force void* to bool)

Am I correct?

Comment: You should know that VC++ 2012 still implements it as `operator void*`. That's the reason for the warning.

Comment: *Any time* you think you need to write '`if(bool(...))`', something has gone horribly wrong somewhere.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

David is correct, and here are the quotes to back him up. In §12.3.2/2, the Standard says

> A conversion function may be explicit (7.1.2), in which case it is only considered as a
>   user-defined conversion for direct-initialization (8.5). Otherwise, user-defined conversions 
>   are not restricted to use in assignments and initializations. [ *Example*:
>
> ```
> class Y { };
> struct Z {
>     explicit operator Y() const;
> };
>
> void h(Z z) {
>     Y y1(z); // OK: direct-initialization
>     Y y2 = z; // ill-formed: copy-initialization
>     Y y3 = (Y)z; // OK: cast notation
> }
> ```
>
> — *end example*]

Some places where this contextual conversion happens is in the operand to `!`, the operands to `&&`, and the condition of an `if`.

So **direct initialisation can make use of explicit conversion operators**, and in §4/3,

> An expression e can be implicitly converted to a type `T` if and only if
>   the declaration `T t=e;` is well-formed, for some invented temporary
>   variable t (8.5). **Certain language constructs require that an
>   expression be converted to a Boolean value. An expression e appearing
>   in such a context is said to be contextually converted to bool and is
>   well-formed if and only if the declaration `bool t(e);` is well-formed**,
>   for some invented temporary variable `t` (8.5)...

So as you can see, the standard specifies as-if direct initialisation for contextual conversions, so that's why explicit conversions work in `if` conditions.

Answer (score 12):

The code is conforming. The explicit conversion operator to `bool` will be called when the object is used as a *condition* automatically. The change in the standard was meant to maintain that same usage while making it a bit safer.

Answer (score 8):

`explicit operator bool` (and *only* `explicit operator bool`) has special language that allows it to be implicitly converted to a `bool` in *certain* circumstances. The specification language for this conversion is "contextually converted to `bool`".

These are the places where the language does boolean testing. The conditional expression used by an `if/while/for` is "contextually converted to `bool`". As are the logical operators and the conditional operator (`?:`).

So while you can't do these:

```
bool b = std::getline(fin, str);
void func(bool) {}
func(std::getline(fin, str));
```

You can do these:

```
while(std::getline(fin, str)) {...}
for(;std::getline(fin, str);) {...}
if(std::getline(fin, str) && somethingElse) {...}
```